# How to pull all products and their attributes off Magento using SOAP v2

Tags: xml, magento, soap

After three days of occasionally fruitful headbanging I am able to pull a collection of products off a Magento website and obtain the extra attributes for a specific product, but I really need a full dump of all products and their attributes.
So this works for an individual product:

```
$sku='HHAM-6';

$attributes = new stdClass();
$attributes->attributes = array('description', 'short_description', 'price');
$list = $client->catalogProductInfo($session, $sku, NULL, $attributes,'');

print_r($list);
```

and this works to get the basic info on all products:

```
$params = '';

$result = $client->catalogProductList($session, $params);
print_r($result);
```

So how do I meld the two? The output of the latter includes:

```
        [product_id] => 1
        [sku] => HHAM-6
```

How do I then integrate the first routine for each product? Some kind of foreach construct?

Sorry if this is too obvious but any assistance welcome.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

API method `catalogProductList` always return only next attributes:

```
        $result[] = array(
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
            'name'       => $product->getName(),
            'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
            'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
            'category_ids' => $product->getCategoryIds(),
            'website_ids'  => $product->getWebsiteIds()
        );
```

See \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Api\V2.php line 82 (or somewhere around it).

You can get array of all products with `catalogProductList` and then foreach it and get attributes for each product with `catalogProductInfo`. But why not go to admin and use **System->Import/Export->Export** and export all products to csv?

Answer (score 0):

For SOAP v1 I found it in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api.php line 108